# About package installation in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

How to install g cc/g++ compiler, auto make, X11 lib,free glut, GT K+ 2.0 and wxGTK-2.8.11 in Ubuntu by using synaptic packet manager or terminal.
I Want to know if these packages are by default in Ubuntu OS or do I need to download from their website and install.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is the command-line tool for handling packages, and may be considered the user's "back-end" to other tools using the APT library. For installation, `apt-get install` is used. You can put multiple package names after the install i.e

```
sudo apt-get install gcc freeglut  (you can add more)
```

You can read more about apt-get from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)

Comment: @user192206 instead thanks you can select the answer that help you the most as the correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the list of packages installed in your system with Synaptic. Open it and click on *Status* (lower left) and then in the left hand list select *Installed*. You can then use the filter to search for the packages you want.

I don't have a fresh Ubuntu install at the moment, but I believe that gcc, automake, gtk and X11 come installed by default.

To install a missing package select *All* in the left hand list, use the filter to search for the desired package; right click on the package name and select *Mark for Installation*. When you have select all the packages you want just click on the *Apply* button.